# I make a login page and I want to show user info name Address etc when I successfully login

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is controller code for Login,
This is User Login Controller code where I authenticating user Email ID and password when user login redirected to Home Controller where I want to show user info

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]

public ActionResult Login(UserLogin login, string ReturnUrl = ""){
         string message = "";
         using (LoginEntities dc = new LoginEntities()){
              var v = dc.Users.Where(a => a.EmailID == login.EmailID).FirstOrDefault();
              var n = dc.Users.Where(a => a.Password == login.Password).FirstOrDefault();
              if (v != null || n != null ){
                   if (string.Compare(Crypto.Hash(login.Password), v.Password) == 0){
                        int timeout = login.RememberME ? 525600 : 20;
                        var ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(login.EmailID,login.RememberME,timeout);
                        string encrypted = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
                        var cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encrypted);
                        cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(timeout);
                        cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

                        if (Url.IsLocalUrl(ReturnUrl)){
                            return Redirect(ReturnUrl);
                        }
                        else{
                            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        message = "Invalid Credential Provided";
                    }
                }
                else {
                    message = "Invalid Credential Provided";
                }
            }
            ViewBag.Message = message;
            return View();
            }
```

Home Controller and index action where I redirect when I login,
This is Home Controller Where I redirected After Logging successfully please some one give a code for home controller and index action where i can  Get Id of user That login and and and tell me how to show that in view

```
public class HomeController : Controller{
        LoginEntities db = new LoginEntities();
        // GET: Home
        [Authorize]
        public ActionResult Index(){
            if (Session.Contents.Count == 0){
                RedirectToAction("Login", "User");
            }

            return View();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated my code below, This might or might not work coz its coded here manually  not on  actual VS :P

// /Controller/TestController.cs

```
namespace XXXX.Controllers
{ 
   public class TestController : Controller
   {
        public ActionResult User()
        {
           String UserId = User.Identity.GetUserId().ToString(); 
           ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

            var rs = db.Users.Find(UserId);
            var model = new UserViewModel
            { 
                UserName = rs.UserName,
                FirstName = rs.FirstName,
                LastName = rs.LastName,
                Email = rs.Email
             };
             db.Dispose();
             return View(model);
        }
   }
}
```

// /Models/UserViewModel.cs

```
namespace XXXX.Models
{  
   public class UserViewModel
  {
     public string Id { get; set; } 
     public string UserName { get; set; } 
     public string Email { get; set; }  
     public string FirstName { get; set; }  
     public string LastName { get; set; } 
  }
}
```

// /Views/Test/User.cshtml

```
@model XXXX.Models.UsersCreateViewModel

<p>
  @Html.Raw(Model.FirstName)
</p>
```

above is just a sample you can use the info further

Comment: Fernan Vacina  I just need when i click on login button  the user that login can  see his First name last name date etc that are persent in User Model ...where i have to write that code and how to pass it to view

Comment: Hi @Shahab added example above hope that helps (take note that is not tested if it actually works but the logic should be in the code on how it should be called)